# Where can I find or how can I create my .prm files for MODIS Reprojection Tool?

Tags: coordinate-system, modis, modis-reprojection-tool

I am tying to reproject my images into ggrs87 and I can't find a .prm file to do that is there a place where I can find such a file or a document that can guide me through my problem?I also thought that I could just reproject my images to another projection and then, when I am finished with my processes I can reproject them into another projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MRT has limited projection options. You may need to first project all your data in MRT (it can be geographic), then reproject it to your desired projection using another software package.

To batch process your data in MRT, create a parameter file in the interface by first entering all your desired parameters. I suggest using a geographic coordinate system (output projection type) with the WGS1984 datum (in edit projection parameters). Then simply choose 'save parameter file' to create it. Keep in mind that you can add multiple tiles from the same day to your input so that they will mosaic.

https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/public/mrt41_usermanual_032811.pdf (p.40)

To execute batch processing...in the command terminal your code should look something like this:

```
cd c:\programs\mrt\bin

java -jar MRTBatch.jar -jar c:\path_to_your_folder_containing_only_hdfs -p c:\programs\mrt\path_to_the_folder_containg_the_parameter_file_you_created\parameter_file.prm

c:\programs\mrt\bin\mrtbatch.bat
```

ArcMap has the coordinate system you'd like to use:
Geographic Coordinate Systems > Europe > GGRS 1987

You will need to construct a simple script to batch process the reprojection from WGS1984 to GGRS 1987 in ArcMap, plus any other processes you'd like to execute.

additional reference: [MODIS coastline issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204165/modis-coastline-issue/204178#204178)